# FormArray.value returns an empty array

Tags: angular, formarray, formgroups

I have a FormGroup and a FormArray inside of FormGroup.

FormArray returns values and controls in correct way.
But when I try to get values with FormArray.value, it returns an empty array.

```
console.log('child form here', this.services);
console.log('child form here', this.services['controls']);
```

Where

```
 get services(): FormArray {
    return this.parentgroup.get('services') as FormArray;
 }
```

[Console.log() output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TgpH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

FormArray is not a simple array despite its name, it is a class. So in order to access the controls array you should use this syntax:

```
var myControls = this.services.controls;
```

And then you can get any control object from array by index:

```
var firstInput = myControls[0];
```